# What happens if I invoke shell with directory as first argument?

Tags: shell, unix

What exactly happens when I call `dash` with existing directory as first argument?
For example,

```bash
% mkdir -p tmp_dir
% dash tmp_dir
```

And it exits with code 0.

If I replace `dash` with `bash` or `zsh`, execution fails (and it is was I expected with dash)

```bash
% bash tmp_dir
tmp_dir: tmp_dir: is a directory
```

From the man page, `dash` expects path to script file as its first argument and I known, that in UNIX everything is a file (even if is a directory). But what exactly happens and why dash has such (surprising) behavoir?

Comment: Probably the `dash` author never put in explicit code to check against the input being a directory, and so it fails silently. This doesn't really seem like a programming question in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly happens

```
$ strace dash tmp_dir  2>&1 | grep -E 'open|read'
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "tmp_dir", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(10, 0x561bef5bacc0, 8192)          = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

`dash` process `open()` s the `tmp_dir` and receives a file descriptor. Then it tries to `read()` from the file descriptor and receifves `EISDIR` error.

From https://github.com/danishprakash/dash/blob/a9481f4a453f0ad25d9c9068c7b6e47253532deb/dash.c#L580 `dash` just calls `getchar()` and stops reading upon receiving `EOF`.

`getchar` return `EOF` both on error and on end of file. `dash` doesn't differentiate between these conditions and does not check `errno` for errors and just exits as-if an empty file was read.